# cfdiv submit within another cfdiv submit, only works in FF

Tags: coldfusion, submit, cfform

I have main page which has payment cfdiv, then in payment cfdiv I have shoppingCart cfdiv.

Mainpage.cfm

```
<i><strong>PAYMENTS</strong></i>
<cfajaximport tags ="cfform,cfdiv">
<cfdiv 
  id="myPaymentDIV" 
  bind="url:Payments.cfm?Labware_TTL=#Labware_TTL#&Media_TTL=#Media_TTL#" 
  style="float:inherit" 
  bindOnLoad="true"
/>
```

Payments.cfm

```
<cfinput 
  name="payments" 
  value="Submit Payment" 
  type="submit"
  style="font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; color:##603"
>

<cfajaximport tags ="cfform,cfdiv">
<cfdiv 
  id="EditCartDIV" 
  bind="url:ShoppingCart.cfm?ReqID=#ReqID#&DoWhat=Default" 
  style="float:inherit" 
  bindOnLoad="true"
/>
```

ShoppingCart.cfm

```
<!---Add More Items--->
<a href="ShoppingCart.cfm?ReqID=#ReqID#&DoWhat=ADDMORE">
  <font style="color:##F00; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal; font-size:12px">
    ADD MORE
  </font>
</a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;

<!---Modify---->
<a href="ShoppingCart.cfm?ReqID=#ReqID#&DoWhat=MODIFY">
  <font style="color:##F00; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal; font-size:12px">
    MODIFY
  </font>
</a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;

<cfinput name="ReqID" value="#ReqID#" type="hidden">
<!---Delete--->
<cfinput 
  name="DoWhat" 
  value="RESET CART" 
  type="submit"
  style="font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; color:##F00"
  id="resercartID"
>
```

This works perfectly fine in FF but all other browsers continues with Payment's submit (Submit Payment).

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `<cfform>` tag is missing in Payments.cfm and ShoppingCart.cfm...?

Comment: No both Payments.cfm and ShoppingCart.cfm has its own opening and closing <cfform> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're not nesting forms inside each other with your cfdivs. For example, if your `EditCartDIV` cfdiv is inside the `cfform` tag from payments, then the submit button could get incorrectly associated with the wrong form.

Make sure you close one `cfform` before calling an AJAX container that contains another `cfform`.

Comment: that probably could be the reason. I completely did it in a different way, so I can't concur. Thank you.